# Writing a function that maps a tuple of objects to object containing tuple in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function in Typescript that takes an array of result objects (either successful with data, or failed without data) and returns a single result. If any provided result object has failed, it returns a failed result. Otherwise, it returns a successful result with an array containing the values of all results passed into the function

For example, this is what I'm trying to implement:

```
type Result<T> = { status: 'success', data: T } | { status: 'failure' }

type ResultArray<T extends unknown[]> = readonly [...{
    [K in keyof T]: Result<T[K]>
}]

declare function unwrap<T extends unknown[]>(arr: ResultArray<T>): Result<T>;
```

If all of the objects have a status of "success":

```
unwrap([
    { status: 'success', data: 1 },
    { status: 'success', data: 'a'},
    { status: 'success', data: true}
]) // returns { status: 'success', data: [1, 'a', true] }
```

If one or more of the objects have a status of "failure":

```
unwrap([
    { status: 'failure' },
    { status: 'success', data: 'a'},
    { status: 'success', data: true}
]) // returns { status: 'failure' }
```

I'm trying to do so without violating Typescript's types. While I would normally implement this with `Array.reduce` in plain JS, I do not know of a way to type the reducer to yield the correct return type.

I've tried so far using recursion to unwrap `ResultArray<[T, ...TRest]>` into `Result<T> and` Result` and then combining the two, but was unable to handle the base case where TRest is empty.

Comment: Wait, what? Are you asking for a strongly typed return type as I have done [here](https://tsplay.dev/w8X8Mw), or just a *runtime implementation*? If so, please clarify this in the question as it is currently unclear with the phrases "normally implement this ... in plain JS" and "way to type the reducer ... correct return type".

Answer (score 1):

Deriving the function signature statically is a tall order, and not very useful (unless if you mark all your variables `as const`).

Typing your function will look like this:

```
type Failure = { status: 'failure' };
type Success<T> = { status: 'success', data: T }

const successList = [{ status: 'success', data: 5 }, { status: 'success', data: "hello" }] as const;

declare function reducer<S extends Success<any>>(list: readonly (S | Failure)[]): Failure | Success<S['data']>;

const result = reducer(successList);

if (result.status == "success") {
  console.log(result);
              // ^? Success<5 | "hello>
} else {
  console.log(result);
                // ^? Failure
}
```

As for implementation, you can write it entirely type-safe as follows:

```
function reducer<S extends Success<any>>(list: readonly (S | Failure)[]): Failure | Success<S['data']> {
  if (list.some(x => x.status === 'failure')) return { status: 'failure' };

  const data: S['data'] = list.flatMap(x => x.status === 'success' ? [x.data] : []);
  
  return { status: 'success', data }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option in case you still want to use reduce:

The problem is that the plain js/ts `reduce` function expects the same type for the input and output type. In your case they are different due to the `data` field being an array in the return value.
For this, we can use [_.reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#reduce) instead:

```
    type Result<T> = { status: 'success', data: T } | { status: 'failure' };

    function unwrap<T>(arr: Result<T>[]): Result<T[]> {
        return _.reduce(arr, (prev: Result<T[]>, current: Result<T>) => {
            if (prev.status === 'failure' || current.status === 'failure') {
                return { status: 'failure' }
            } else {
                prev.data.push(current.data)
                return prev;
            }
        }, {
            status: 'success',
            data: []
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and an [overloaded function signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to statically infer the tuple [parameter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters) and return type like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgSwDYFcBOEDKw7BQZygF4oBvKfHPfALigCIAzRVDeqAXwG4AoUSKJhQBjYRHz5suAsTIUqBOvXwixE9tz7hoQ0ePwBJYBAC2AHgAqAPlm61khYQBkcgCa44dC515aBd-QAlcRQkYEsUMCgIAA9jADtXQmC4VwB7eKQQAEE0NDgQMxT0zMKAiSNTMxR4gGt4tIB3eKtWmyIeKEFVfUrzcgBtAGkoBHioWogQNMYoC0iAXS9I4YXouIhEwnJ3HDoxxgg0Oc4oAH4TuniIADcjzitfRhrhYAQMqBrG-LAzTqhhBlKCdYgkklBihksrl8oVIaUzOVDMZzDV6k0Wq0eFYABR4MBeACUdCRwRUYUsjx4z3ir3e4y+Pz+XUB8WB3lBm3B8OheQKZngyHQWEcVmxeMiRLogtYIuk+F4NLpH0ZcF+-1Z7PWYOSEFSUJyfMKMuFUmoUAAPhC9SUsoiehUUdU6g1mm1xfipbAWKbHIqXm8VfFvmrmQCgcAQRsttb9aUYfzyJR5XRKGgxgBzAA0UF2cDOdDRrvGHDFuM9c2J3qFGDNMitSccShUenUObzhZdGIGa00SsDDODTI1EajOtjtsNsIFPtrjktE4N9tbyKqRYx7vLksrZBHbMjHc+XeaPdkPd4XUYaWOOM1kbSACMAFZQGZQfGE3ddLoIWY4x9PgAdMm5pEGBDAtvY9CfnmgFgAQAAW-7PoBeaEhe34QEg+DQBgeBoOMjYpgwzA1hAGgYRw-x4eghHyMRygOvg9Dth4Pg8FRPB3lAGDksAACMsiqmAOIDP8RHUM2TEsbmHh0IJHBZuJ9GSRB0msXsDBwBoSldBJihqSuMmHsAaAoNAVELOhPA8LxoQCahHgYd+UAAPSuQAemcNmamkSAQIBSBpBmOJ2WE-HoW5rlyCBBmMUZGmeFAAz8Tm9DaTmpnmb2PmjmFwAAExCUOaqicpsW0CRs7kZwukxU2hlQYlSjabV5UNfFTWyZpWUWTwVm+PlBW8O5Xm5WyfkBUFIVDZF7n1QxpGyhoPBAA)

```ts
type FailureStatus = { status: "failure" };
type SuccessStatus = { status: "success" };
type SuccessItem<T> = SuccessStatus & { data: T };

type SuccessResult<Tup extends ReadonlyArray<Readonly<SuccessItem<unknown>>>> =
  SuccessItem<{ [K in keyof Tup]: Tup[K] extends { data: infer T } ? T : never }>;

function unwrap<
  const T extends ReadonlyArray<Readonly<SuccessItem<unknown>>>
>(tup: T): SuccessResult<T>;
function unwrap<
  const T extends ReadonlyArray<FailureStatus>
>(tup: T): FailureStatus;
function unwrap<
  const T extends ReadonlyArray<FailureStatus | Readonly<SuccessItem<unknown>>>
>(tup: T): FailureStatus;
function unwrap<
  const T extends ReadonlyArray<{ status: string, data?: unknown }>
>(tup: T): FailureStatus | { status: "success", data: unknown[] };
function unwrap<
  const T extends ReadonlyArray<FailureStatus | Readonly<SuccessItem<unknown>>>
>(tup: T) {
  const data: unknown[] = [];
  for (const obj of tup) {
    if (obj.status === "success") data.push(obj.data);
    else return { status: "failure" };
  }
  return { status: "success", data };
}

const result1 = unwrap([
  { status: "success", data: 1 },
  { status: "success", data: "a" },
  { status: "success", data: true }
]);

result1.data;
      //^? (property) data: readonly [1, "a", true]

console.log(result1); // { status: "success", data: [1, "a", true] }

const result2 = unwrap([
  { status: "failure" },
  { status: "success", data: "a" },
  { status: "success", data: true }
]);

result2;
//^? const result2: FailureStatus

console.log(result2); // { status: "failure" }
```